# Web app sporadically hanging with confusing stack traces

Tags: java, iis-7, coldfusion, stack-trace, coldfusion-9

I've got an app that has some requests hanging and I can't seem to pinpoint the cause. It doesn't happen with every request...only every once in a while. From my very limited understanding of stack traces it appears that perhaps the problem might be with the database but I really have no idea at all or how to verify that.

I'm running

- SQL Server 2008 R2
- IIS 7
- ColdFusion 9 with the ORM
- Coldbox 3.1
- ValidateThis 1.1

Below are the stack traces for two requests, pulled from FusionReactor, that were hung and eventually timed out after five minutes.

```
===================================================================
Stack Trace 1
===================================================================

"jrpp-1583" prio=5 runnable

java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(SocketInputStream.java:???)[Native
Method]
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
jrun.servlet.jrpp.ProxyEndpoint.readFully(ProxyEndpoint.java:581)
jrun.servlet.jrpp.ProxyEndpoint.readFully(ProxyEndpoint.java:573)
jrun.servlet.jrpp.ProxyEndpoint.readInt(ProxyEndpoint.java:591)
jrun.servlet.jrpp.ProxyEndpoint.readString(ProxyEndpoint.java:620)
jrun.servlet.jrpp.ProxyEndpoint.getRealPathFromServer(ProxyEndpoint.java:540)
jrun.servlet.jrpp.ProxyEndpoint.access$000(ProxyEndpoint.java:36)
jrun.servlet.jrpp.ProxyEndpoint$1.fetch(ProxyEndpoint.java:528)
jrunx.util.Cache.get(Cache.java:116)
jrun.servlet.jrpp.ProxyEndpoint.getRealPath(ProxyEndpoint.java:565)
jrun.servlet.WebApplicationService.getResource(WebApplicationService.java:1028)
jrun.servlet.JRunServletContext.getRealPath(JRunServletContext.java:132)
coldfusion.runtime.ServletContextWrapper.doGetRealPath(ServletContextWrapper.java:166)
coldfusion.runtime.ServletContextWrapper._doGetRealPath(ServletContextWrapper.java:112)
coldfusion.runtime.ServletContextWrapper.getRealPath(ServletContextWrapper.java:97)
coldfusion.runtime.RuntimeServiceImpl.getRealPath(RuntimeServiceImpl.java:999)
coldfusion.filter.FusionContext.getRealPath(FusionContext.java:759)
coldfusion.util.Utils.expandPath(Utils.java:434)
coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.ExpandPath(CFPage.java:3074)
cfFrameworkSupertype2ecfc551651643$funcINCLUDEUDF.runFunction(E:\WebRoot\Production\CF\projects\Backhauls2\frameworks\coldbox\3_1\system\FrameworkSupertype.cfc:364)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472)
coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:405)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368)
coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:220)
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2582)
cfRenderer2ecfc1460685596$funcINIT.runFunction(E:\WebRoot\Production\CF\projects\Backhauls2\frameworks\coldbox\3_1\system\plugins\Renderer.cfc:57)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472)
coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:405)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368)
coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:220)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:491)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:337)
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2360)
cfPluginService2ecfc1482130609$funcNEW.runFunction(E:\WebRoot\Production\CF\projects\Backhauls2\frameworks\coldbox\3_1\system\web\services\PluginService.cfc:111)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472)
coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:405)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368)
coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:517)
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2547)
cfPluginService2ecfc1482130609$funcGET.runFunction(E:\WebRoot\Production\CF\projects\Backhauls2\frameworks\coldbox\3_1\system\web\services\PluginService.cfc:151)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472)
coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:405)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368)
coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:220)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:491)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:337)
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2360)
cfController2ecfc877306041$funcGETPLUGIN.runFunction(E:\WebRoot\Production\CF\projects\Backhauls2\frameworks\coldbox\3_1\system\web\Controller.cfc:328)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472)
coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:405)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368)
coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:220)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:491)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:337)
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2360)
cfColdbox2ecfc1686952617$funcPROCESSCOLDBOXREQUEST.runFunction(E:\WebRoot\Production\CF\projects\Backhauls2\frameworks\coldbox\3_1\system\Coldbox.cfc:261)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:405)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368)
coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:220)
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2582)
cfColdbox2ecfc1686952617$funcONREQUESTSTART.runFunction(E:\WebRoot\Production\CF\projects\Backhauls2\frameworks\coldbox\3_1\system\Coldbox.cfc:353)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:405)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368)
coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:220)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:491)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:337)
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2360)
cfApplication2ecfc612734261$funcONREQUESTSTART.runFunction(E:\WebRoot\Production\CF\projects\Backhauls2\Application.cfc:85)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:405)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368)
coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:220)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:491)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:337)
coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.invoke(AppEventInvoker.java:88)
coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.onRequestStart(AppEventInvoker.java:258)
coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:349)
coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:94)
coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70)
coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)
coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62)
coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:200)
coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)
com.intergral.fusionreactor.filter.FusionReactorFilter.b(FusionReactorFilter.java:376)
com.intergral.fusionreactor.filter.FusionReactorFilter.c(FusionReactorFilter.java:254)
com.intergral.fusionreactor.filter.FusionReactorFilter.doFilter(FusionReactorFilter.java:164)
jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)

===================================================================
Stack Trace 2
===================================================================

"jrpp-1519" prio=5 runnable

java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(SocketInputStream.java:???)[Native
Method]
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
jrun.servlet.jrpp.ProxyEndpoint.readFully(ProxyEndpoint.java:581)
jrun.servlet.jrpp.ProxyEndpoint.readFully(ProxyEndpoint.java:573)
jrun.servlet.jrpp.ProxyEndpoint.readInt(ProxyEndpoint.java:591)
jrun.servlet.jrpp.ProxyEndpoint.readString(ProxyEndpoint.java:620)
jrun.servlet.jrpp.ProxyEndpoint.getHeader(ProxyEndpoint.java:762)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getHeader(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:124)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getHeader(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:124)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getHeader(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:124)
com.intergral.fusionreactor.filter.surrogate.e.getHeader(FusionReactorServletRequestProxy.java:247)
coldfusion.runtime.CgiScope.resolve(CgiScope.java:221)
coldfusion.runtime.CgiScope.containsName(CgiScope.java:301)
coldfusion.runtime.CgiScope.search(CgiScope.java:334)
coldfusion.runtime.NeoPageContext.searchScopes(NeoPageContext.java:766)
coldfusion.runtime.NeoPageContext.findAttribute(NeoPageContext.java:638)
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._get(CfJspPage.java:296)
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._get(CfJspPage.java:283)
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._get(CfJspPage.java:271)
cfBackhaul2ecfc1977538551$funcSAVE.runFunction(E:\WebRoot\Production\CF\projects\Backhauls2\model\domain\entities\Backhaul.cfc:285)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368)
coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:220)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:491)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:337)
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2360)
cfBackhaul2ecfc1792941188$funcSAVE.runFunction(E:\WebRoot\Production\CF\projects\Backhauls2\handlers\Backhaul.cfc:327)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368)
coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:517)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:496)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:355)
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2301)
coldfusion.tagext.lang.InvokeTag.doEndTag(InvokeTag.java:389)
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2723)
cfController2ecfc877306041$funcINVOKER.runFunction(E:\WebRoot\Production\CF\projects\Backhauls2\frameworks\coldbox\3_1\system\web\Controller.cfc:699)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472)
coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:405)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368)
coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:220)
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2582)
cfController2ecfc877306041$funcRUNEVENT.runFunction(E:\WebRoot\Production\CF\projects\Backhauls2\frameworks\coldbox\3_1\system\web\Controller.cfc:584)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472)
coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:405)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368)
coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:517)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:496)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:355)
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2301)
cfColdbox2ecfc1686952617$funcPROCESSCOLDBOXREQUEST.runFunction(E:\WebRoot\Production\CF\projects\Backhauls2\frameworks\coldbox\3_1\system\Coldbox.cfc:243)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:405)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368)
coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:220)
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2582)
cfColdbox2ecfc1686952617$funcONREQUESTSTART.runFunction(E:\WebRoot\Production\CF\projects\Backhauls2\frameworks\coldbox\3_1\system\Coldbox.cfc:353)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:405)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368)
coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:220)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:491)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:337)
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2360)
cfApplication2ecfc612734261$funcONREQUESTSTART.runFunction(E:\WebRoot\Production\CF\projects\Backhauls2\Application.cfc:85)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:405)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368)
coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:220)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:491)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:337)
coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.invoke(AppEventInvoker.java:88)
coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.onRequestStart(AppEventInvoker.java:258)
coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:349)
coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:94)
coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70)
coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)
coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62)
coldfusion.filter.RequestThrottleFilter.invoke(RequestThrottleFilter.java:126)
coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:200)
coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)
com.intergral.fusionreactor.filter.FusionReactorFilter.b(FusionReactorFilter.java:376)
com.intergral.fusionreactor.filter.FusionReactorFilter.c(FusionReactorFilter.java:254)
com.intergral.fusionreactor.filter.FusionReactorFilter.doFilter(FusionReactorFilter.java:164)
jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the entire stack trace? I would expect to see a trace of an exception, but I don't see any...

Comment: Yeah, that's all I was given. I pulled it out of FusionReactor, our server monitoring software.

Comment: Looks to me that your coldfusion code is making some sort of external web request but without any IO timeouts.  It would be interesting to see if there are any outgoing sockets ESTABLISHED on your server and see if you can add IO timeouts to the calls.

Answer (score 0):

Dustin, I'd look to the Database, as you suggest. Either start a new SQL Server trace session, or watch the database in the Activity Monitor. You'll be looking for deadlocks, long-running queries, etc.

For reading these stack traces, sometimes SeeStack can help: http://www.seefusion.com/seestack/seestack.cfm

In addition, since you're using ORM, I'd turn on logging (logsql=true in Application.cfc ormSettings struct). You need to be sure that you're not inadvertently loading giant object graphs, which can cause this behavior.